# setting UIImageVIew of UITableViewCell as opaque

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I and profiling using Core Animation and my UIImageView on a UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle is showing as blending (in red) instead of being opaque.

I am setting the image like so:

```
    // This is just a helper method that loads a .jpg from the disk
    UIImage *img = [Helpers getThumbnailImageIfExists:[obj valueForKey:@"PhotoName"] withManufacturer:self.client.ManufacturerID];
    cell.imageView.image = img;
   [cell.imageView setOpaque:YES];
```

I thought this should do it but it still shows as not being opaque.  I am having the same issues with some UIButtons that I am adding to my contentView

Comment: check if the img you are getting from Helpers method is not nil

Comment: I can see the image so I know it is not nil

Answer (score 0):

Your image probably contains an Alpha channel. Even though you're setting it as Opaque iOS renders it as `semi-transparent`.  Try removing the alpha channel from the Image via Photoshop:

Layer > Background From Layer

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is a .jpg so no alpha channel, wonder if it is because it is getting loaded as UIImage as NSData